# Symfony2 how to minify html code

Tags: html, symfony, minify, symfony-2.7, html-compression

I'm using symfony 2.7 then I want to minify my html code.
is there a working bundle to do that?

I tried 
https://github.com/MatTheCat/HtmlCompressorBundle
  but I didn't see any change.
Can you help me with that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this bundle . it's work fine

> https://packagist.org/packages/sema/minifier-bundle

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's specify symfony/framework-bundle: ~2.1 but I'm using 2.7
Are you sure it will be working?

Comment: I tried then I got this   error: **ContextErrorException in HTML.php line 239:
Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'JSMinPlus' not found**